# Prevent unauthorized user from accessing PDF file

Tags: html, mysql, python-3.x, django, pdf

I have a web application that allows users to download PDF files. The users are supposed to login or register (if not already registered) and after verification of credentials are allowed to view or download PDFs. Hence, only authorized users are able to access the PDFs. My question is, is there a way in which I can prevent the authorized users from sharing the PDFs with other unauthorized users?
I have read about password encryption, digital certificates and Digital Rights Management. I also know that we can hide the toolbar in the browser using embed tag and prevent users from downloading the files. I have also read so many posts saying that preventing users from sharing the PDFs after it has been downloaded is simply not possible. But **I just wanna know if it is possible to somehow embed a key with the PDF when it is being downloaded and invoke a script (preferably Python) to verify the user, when the user tries to open the PDF**? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no reliable way to do this. PDF DRM essentially involves making a "broken" PDF file (using custom encryption probably), that only specific PDF reader software knows how to process and that specific reader handles the DRM part.